# Net Core Identity one role per user

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-identity

I want to have only one `MyIdentityRole` per `MyIdentityUser`. My Current Code:

```
public class MyIdentityUser: IdentityUser
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Image { get; set; }
    public string PersonalNumber { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public bool IsDeleted { get; set; }
    public string MyIdentityRoleId { get; set; }
    public MyIdentityRole MyIdentityRole { get; set; }
}

public class MyIdentityRole: IdentityRole
{
    public List<MyIdentityUser> MyIdentityUsers { get; set; }
    public List<MenuPermission> MenuPermissions { get; set; }
}
```

Controller side Code:

```
private readonly UserManager<MyIdentityUser> _UserManager;
public AdminSideMenuViewComponent(IMenuService menuService, UserManager<MyIdentityUser> userManager)
{
  this._MenuService = menuService;
  this._UserManager = userManager;
}
public async Task<IViewComponentResult> InvokeAsync()
{
  var user = await _UserManager.GetUserAsync(HttpContext.User);
  var role = user?.MyIdentityRole; // is always null
  var roleId = user?.MyIdentityRoleId; // returns actual roleId as it should
}
```

A small problem is that when I get a user with `RoleManager` everything is filled correctly, but
navigation property `MyIdentityRole` in `MyIdentityUser` is always **NULL** though `MyIdentityRoleId` shows correct role Id. 
In database `[dbo].[AspNetUsers]` has a foreign key `MyIdentityRoleId` generated by codefirst migration.

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: First, why use such a restriction? `Roles` is always available and already contains that single `Role`. Second, what you posted doesn't show how you customized Identity. In fact, you use the same class name twice to inherit from different base classes. This won't compile

Comment: Please add more detail. How does the ;RoleManager' load the data? Are you using Entity Framework? If 'yes' my guess is that your model might not be defined in a manner that loads the reference or auto loading is disabled, in which case you might have to eager load it.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos copying error... sorry. I corrected it and added some more code.

Comment: @Van it's Entity Framework Core and Core Identity. I just want to make default many to many relationship between roles and users to be one to many for user. I want one role per user.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos first, more performance probably, second, is there a way to customize identity to use one role per user? i am just asking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> but navigation property MyIdentityRole in MyIdentityUser is always NULL though MyIdentityRoleId shows correct role Id.

Try this:

```
var username = HttpContext.User.Identity.Name;
var user = await _userManager.Users.Include(u => u.MyIdentityRole)
                                   .Where(u => u.UserName == username).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
var roles = user?.MyIdentityRole; 
var roleId = user?.MyIdentityRoleId;
```

Result:
[image]
Another simple way:

```
var role = User.FindAll(c => string.Equals(c.Type, ClaimTypes.Role)).First().Value;
```